# Kotlin - Error: Could not find or load main class _DefaultPackage

Tags: kotlin

I followed the Kotlin tutorial for eclipse here : [Getting Started With Eclipse Luna](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started-eclipse.html)

However, I'm running into this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class _DefaultPackage
```

Anyone who knows to get around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a severe bug ([KT-10221](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10221)) in automatic generation of Launch Configuration in plugin version 0.4.0. It was fixed in 0.5.0 so the recommendend way to workaround is to update plugin.

The source of the problem was that the plugin used an old pattern for generating name of the class for main function that had been abandoned by Kotlin compiler.

It's possible to workaround it by editing launch configuration (*Eclipse Menu -> Run -> Run Configurations...*) by hand and changing *Main class* field in *Java Application* group. If the file is named *hello.kt* with no package directive, as it is described in tutorial, than corrected string should be **HelloKt**.

If file has name *other.kt* with package *my.tutorial* than the *Main Class* should contain *my.tutorial.HelloKt*. You can read more about it in the section [Package-Level Functions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions) of *Calling Kotlin From Java* page.

Comment: In 2020 I am getting this error and this solution did not work for me.

Comment: Using Koltin `1.5`, still same error. The workaround didn't work either

Comment: I think you miss `Kt` while run `kotlin` command for example `kotlin Hello` instead your have to call `kotlin HelloKt`

Answer (score 2):

I have been getting the same issue. And after putting the right compiler output path, it got resolved.

`Go to Project -> Project Compiler output :
In the text box, fill this:
[Absolute Path]/{Project Name}/out`

Comment: I don't see these options in Eclipse 2018-12.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was having this problem while trying to run the program using the Application Gradle plugin. The problem was in the `mainClassName` property using single quotes instead of double ones

This didn't work:

```
mainClassName = 'demo.HelloWorldKt'
```

With double quotes, it works:

```
mainClassName = "demo.HelloWorldKt"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after I installed the correct JDK. I first had JDK 11 but the tutorial I did was with JDK 8 so after I installed this and set it in the "installed JREs" options it found the main class without having any "mainClassName" or any other option in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it worked in a fresh eclipse workspace. Possibly, the Kotlin eclipse plugin is not playing well with other plugins (in my case, PyDev).

Answer (score -1):

I'm creating a Kotlin Application with JavaFX and I had this issue until I went to:
  Run > Run Configurations > Java Application > Common
I unticked "Allocate console" and it fixed the issue.