# Run as Kotlin Application missing - eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I have eclipse "Oxygen" version for which I have installed the kotlin plugin by referring the official kotlin [site](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started-eclipse.html) . I have also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506227/unable-to-run-kotlin-application-in-eclipse) page on stack overflow, but none of the methods have helped me. I am unable to see "Run as kotlin application" option. This might be a duplicate question, but the original question's answers have not helped me.

Comment: What steps did you perform? How would someone reproduce exactly what you've done, not what it says in the instructions, what you did?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Run Kotlin Application in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506227/unable-to-run-kotlin-application-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

Remove curly braces around class and it will work :

```
class Hello 
fun main () {
    println("Hello World !!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure why you should do something like this but it worked

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put the main() inside the class, after putting main() at the top level it worked.

Here are the screen shots for the reference:

**Correct :** 
[image]

**Incorrect:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why this work...

```
fun main() {
    println("Hola Mundo")
//  if (args.size == 0)
//      println("Te olvidaste los argumentos ...")
}
```

and this don't

```
fun main(args : List<String>) {
    println("Hola Mundo")
//  if (args.size == 0)
//      println("Te olvidaste los argumentos ...")
}
```

when I add parameters to main function, the menu option *Run as Kotlin* ... disappear!

Any Idea ?

Best Regards

Answer (score -1):

I had to ensure the project had Kotlin Nature (go to properties -> project natures) and then open the Kotlin perspective and then i saw the run as Kotlin application.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the Kotlin Plugin Version. There was a bug in one of the releases. Also if that doesn't work, switch to a newer version of the IDE, maybe Photon. That should make it work.

Comment: What I have read is that the Kotlin plugin does not work in the more recent versions.