# Eclipse Kotlin plugin not compiling Kotlin classes

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

Using Eclipse 2018.12, I've installed the Eclipse Kotlin plugin (0.8.20.20200316-1305), created a Kotlin project (using the "New..." options under "Kotlin") and wrote a "Hello World!" program:

`Test.kt:`

```
fun main() = System.out.println("Hello World!")
```

[image]

However, when I try to run it I get the message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class TestKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestKt
```

Upon further inspection it seems the class has never been compiled. There is no corresponding `.class` file anywhere. Under the project directory I see Eclipse configuration directory `.settings` and files `.project` and `.classpath`. Besides that, I have an empty `bin` directory and a `src` directory with `Test.kt` only.

I found two similar questions about this in SO:
In [Unable to Run Kotlin Application in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506227/unable-to-run-kotlin-application-in-eclipse), the accepted answer simply indicates working with a new version of Eclipse and Kotlin plugin, both older than what I have now. Besides, the problem may have been solved in that case due to a new installation rather than the version.
[Kotlin - Error: Could not find or load main class _DefaultPackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979322/kotlin-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-defaultpackage) is quite old and the accepted answer does not apply anymore. It was about not naming the main class properly, but in my case there is not even a byte code file to be found.

Running "Project -> Compile Kotlin classes" had no effect.

How can I get this simple example to run?

**Update**: I've updated to 2020-06 (not that it should matter since Eclipse Kotlin lists 2018-12 in its requirements) and replaced Zuly by AdoptOpenJDK HotSpotJDK 11. The error persists. The Eclipse log does not show any related messages.

**Update 2**: re-created the project in a brand-new workspace but the problem persists.

Comment: I guess you mean Eclipse 2018-12 which is 6(!) releases behind. Please upgrade or name the technical reasons that prevent you from doing so. Maybe your issue is caused by an (also outdated?) Zulu JRE/JDK (see e.g. [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32145)). Do you face the same issue with a [AdoptOpenJDK HotSpot JDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)? If none of this helps, look at the Eclipse Error log for more details.

Comment: I've updated to 2020-06 (not that it should matter since Eclipse Kotlin lists 2018-12 in its requirements) and replaced Zuly by AdoptOpenJDK HotSpotJDK 11. The error persists. The Eclipse log does not show any related messages.