# Kotlin - Application project template - error main class not found

Tags: kotlin

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 (Community Edition) - Build #IC-211.6693.111, built on April 6, 2021.
I created a new kotlin project - project template(JVM): Application, built system: Gradle Kotlin,
project JDK:1.8 version 1.8.0_281.
In the “scr/main/kotlin” folder, I created a kotlin file with a simple code like "fun main(){println(“Hi!”)}.
When I tried to run the file(the build was ok), I got this error: “Could not find or load main class MyAppKt”.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add your main class to the `build.gradle` file?

```
mainClassName = "projectPackage.MyAppKt"
```

I assume if you are adding the `MyAppKt` file manually it is not added to the `build.grale`. But clearly more information about the project would help here. Meanwhile check this post [Kotlin - Error: Could not find or load main class _DefaultPackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979322/kotlin-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-defaultpackage)